# Ubuntu + UNO R3 - Avrdude programmer is not responding

Tags: arduino, ubuntu-14.04, arduino-uno, avrdude

I'm trying to use a chinese Arduino-Uno (Uno R3) into an Ubuntu 14.04 but I can't upload my sketch.

When I ran the command:

```
sudo avrdude -v -v -v -v -c avrisp -p m328p -P /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I get this result:

```
avrdude: Version 6.0.1, compiled on Oct 21 2013 at 15:55:32
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2009 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/root/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
         Using Programmer              : avrisp
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

I already try:

1. Check if the cable and/or connectors does not have microcuts;
2. Verify the pins RX and TX;
3. Reset button on the board while the upload;
4. Follow all the steps described on http://playground.arduino.cc/Linux/Ubuntu.

Can you help me fix this error?

PS: My board is just like this [one](http://www.dx.com/p/uno-r3-atmega328p-uno-r3-development-board-deep-blue-285620#.V5Zg3O0vmgo).

Comment: Under 4, did you do `sudo usermod -aG dialout <myuser>` and logout & login (or restart)? Also: How did you install avrdude? apt? Compiled from source? downloaded binary? (I assume apt because of `System wide configuration file is "/etc/avrdude.conf"`)

Comment: Hi  showp1984,

 Thanks for the help. I ran the command sudo usermod -aG dialout <myuser> in the described tests. The avrdude was installed through the apt-get. Do you have any idea to help me to fix this problem?
 
 Best regards,
 Ricardo

Comment: Just to be sure: You did substitute `<myuser>` for your actual user name? :) Also: Are you sure the Arduino works? Does flashing work through the Arduino IDE?

Comment: Hi showp1984, thanks again for the support. I changed `<myuser>` for my user name. In fact I'm beginner with arduino and this is my first test with this board. So I think that the Arduino works, because when I plug the board using the USB cable a red led turn on and the Arduino IDE identifies the interface ttyUSB0 and the board Arduino/Genuino Uno. There are other tests I can make to be sure if the Arduino is working?

Comment: Sadly that doesn't mean that the Arduino works. The ttyUSB0 and Uno recognition are solely telling you that the USB-to-Serial chip on the board works (the 328P is connected to the USB-to-Serial chip). Not if the 328P works in itself. I have a similar board to yours here, and when I ordered two of it one was DOA. You need to verify the 328p works, you can do it by flashing with the default Arduino IDE and seeing if that gets you closer. Also: check the traces on your pcb for interruptions/scratches. That error you got means the 328p is not sending anything back. (could be a faulty tx line)

Comment: Hi showp1984, thank you very much for your explanations that are really useful. I followed yours instructions and sadly the board don't works. Reading your advices I suppose that I have a problem with the 328p. I'm thinking in to talk with the board seller in order to try to change the board. What you think?

Comment: First, try this: Your unit might just be missing the bootloader. Do you have another Arduino available? You can then use it to flash the bootloader on your defunct device: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP That way you will bypass the USB-to-Serial on your defunct device and connect directly to the chip. If that fails, return it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-c arduino`, it toggles DTR to restart MCU and start bootloader for few seconds.

BTW: Reset button must be pressed almost precisely just before retry and it is not as easy as it sounds.

Comment: Hi KIIV,

 Thank you for the help. I tried to use the `-c arduino` option and I get this error message:
`avrdude: Send: 0 [30]   [20] 
avrdude: ser_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
`

Do you have any idea to help me to fix this problem?

Best regards,
Ricardo